# dynamically add js variable value in django template url with appname and namespace

Tags: javascript, python, django

> I have multiple apps in project and using appname and namespace for
>   urls. I need to dynamically add js variable value in django template
>   url with app name. If I write without appname like --

```
var temp =23
var href = "{% url 'report_page' id=0 %}".replace(/0/, temp.toString())
```

> It is giving desired result as--

```
"{% url 'report_page' location_id=23 %}"
```

> But when I use appname its not working for me e.g

```
var href = "{% url 'appname : report_page' id=0 %}".replace(/0/, temp.toString())
```

> Let me give you the exact code: In django template:

```
<html>
<a href="{% url 'appname : report_page' id=0 %}">Report</a>
</html>
```

var href = "{% url 'appname : report_page' id=0 %}".replace(/0/, temp.toString())

> In url.py of the appname:

```
appname = 'appname'
  urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^report-page$', views.report_page, name='report_page'),
    url(r'^report-page/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$', views.report_page, name='report_page'),
]+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

> In views:

```
def report_page(request):
    import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
    # location_id = request.GET['id']
    return render(
        request,
        'report.html',
        {'id' : request.user.id, 'id' : ''}
    )
```

> Note: I'm using django 1.11 and I have also tried below one but getting empty string:

```
var temp =$('#check_id').val() <a href="{% url 'appname: report_page' %}?id="+temp;>Report</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankit, The logic helped I made some changes though,      id = $('#id').val()
      var arr  = $('.set-select-volume').attr('href').split('/')
      arr[arr.length] = id.toString()
      $(".set-select-volume").attr('href', arr.join('/'))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using with djagno url such as `{% url 'appname : report_page' id=0 %}`, when django template will rendering it will convert into the like `/appname/report-page/0/`,
it's solutions is,
first you will to take `a` tag attributes value then change this.
please find below solutions.

`var arr = $("a").attr('href').split('/')
arr[arr.length-2]=777 # demo value
$("a").attr('href',arr.join('/'))`

Comment: Thanks Ankit it helped me, just I change in your answer, it will not generate "/appname" only url will be there no appname